# Is it possible to mark a function to not be optimized out?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, x86, clang

Given a (inline void-returning nullary) function `f` that doesn't have side effects:

```
inline void f() { /*...*/ }
```

Is it possible to write an inline function `g` that calls `f` but won't be optimized out by the implementation:

```
inline void g() { [[dont_optimize_this_away ???]] f(); }
```

Is there some way to tell the compiler "call f and inline the assembly, but don't optimize those instructions away"?

I don't think there is a way to do this in standard C++20. (or is there?)

...but is there a platform-specific way to do it on `x86-64` with `gcc`, `clang` and/or `msvc` ?  Some kind of instrinsic / compile builtin / attribute?

Comment: What instructions would you expect the compiler to emit, for an inline function that doesn’t do anything?

Comment: @Sneftel: For example, let's say it was `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++);` I would expect it to emit `mov eax=100; loop: dec eax; jnz loop;`.  Or let's say I put those instructions in an inline assembly block explicitly.

Comment: I suppose part of the confusion could be caused by the assumption that assembly is generated before inlining. That's not how modern compilers work; it loses valuable optimization opportunities. A symbolic representation is inlined, which in this case is "nothing".

Comment: If you did that loop in the middle of a function, rather than by calling a separate function that did that, wouldn’t you expect the optimiser to remove the loop entirely? It has no visible effects, after all.

Comment: @MSalters: Ok lets suppose I wrote an inline assembly block - is there a way to tell the compiler to really emit those instructions and not optimize them away.

Comment: In the case of that `for` loop, you could add the `volatile` qualifier to `int i`.

Comment: @AdrianMole: That would introduce a side effect, and the question specifically says there aren't.

Comment: @MSalters Not sure what that side effect would be, as `i` no longer exists after the loop ends.

Comment: @MSalters: Then I suspect maybe what I'm really after is a way to turn off optimization for a specific function.

Comment: @AdrianMole: The observable effect would be 100 writes to a `volatile`. In C++, that is formally an observable side effect. That's precisely why `volatile` stops the optimizer.

Comment: One idea is to pass the return value somewhere. `dont_discard(f());` and then define `dont_discard` in another file where the optimizer can't see it. Obviously not guaranteed to work (especially with LTO)

Comment: In general, the answer to this question as asked is "no".   The C++ standard only requires that observable side effects (e.g. output, changes of a `volatile` variable) are produced.   Timing is not an observable side effect (at least, in C++ and quite a few other languages - the definition does not extend to what (say) a system task monitor outside the running program can measure) which is why functions (or loops, or whatever) that are deemed to have no observable effects are often optimised out entirely.

Comment: @BoP: this question forgot to mention that this is a followup to [Best approximation for nanosecond-accurate sleep function with compile-time duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72781467) . That doesn't work well for tiny sleeps on the order of the cost of making a single system call, and they don't actually want to delay for time, they want to delay for execution cost to try to mock up a test of genetic algorithms that take a function pointer as an arg.

Comment: Note that the optimizer will optimize `f` into the empty function. So even if you make the optimizer call `f` in `g` it will just be `f: ret`. What you need is to add something to `f` that has an observable effect for the compiler but does nothing, like `volatile asm("")` or `volatile asm("":::memory);`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044490/16619026) post,
you can use `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))` like:

```
inline void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) g() { [[dont_optimize_this_away ???]] f(); }
```

Comment: That generates horrible code.,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? Looking at the disassembly of release looks like it's still in there. (Windows pragma: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=msvc-170)

```
inline void f() {
    //std::cout << "I do a thing";
}

#pragma optimize( "", off ) 
inline void g() {
    f();
}
#pragma optimize( "", on )

int main()
{
    g();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. For example Google benchmark has [benchmark::DoNotOptimize](https://benchmark.docsforge.com/master/api/benchmark/DoNotOptimize/).

Just copy its implementation to your code and apply it for index variable for this dummy loop of yours `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++);` form comment under a question.

Here is [technical explanation how it works for gcc](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk?t=2451) (note it is old source so name of function is different).

Comment: Certainly worth mentioning, but `DoNotOptimize` operates on a reference (essentially just casting it to volatile), whereas the question asks for a way to apply it to the function `g` (without modifying `f`).   The `for` example is just one possible body of `f`.